# Use jQuery to Change Image for Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am using a script that creates a social wall or a wall of all of my social feeds. This script has the ability to filter social networks and has icons at the top. It works great but on mobile devices the icons are very small. I have considered using CSS Media Queries to make them bigger but that will distort the icons thus I must replace the icons with larger ones.

The problem is the script is generating the code dynamically and I cannot edit this code. The generated code looks like this:

```
<li class="active f-facebook">
  <a data-filter=".dcsns-facebook" data-group="dc-filter" rel="facebook" href="#filter">
     <img alt="" src="/images/icons/facebook.png">
  </a>
</li>
```

I would need to change the image to a larger version after the script has loaded and only for mobile devices of a certain size.

I do not know what to try using jQuery to do this. Can someone point me in the correct direction or assist me with a solution?

Comment: You can check whether `$(window).width()` is less than a certain amount and if so change all of the respective image sources to the larger icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tell you to use CSS instead of script, since some carriers use to disable javascript in their mobile devices and no every device has the same behaviour with scripting.
   In case you use CSS, you need to add a class in your logo and set the with and/or height proportionally. If you set for example with:40%, you can set height:'auto'.

I hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query maybe? They allow you to specify css towards a certain device attributes.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/